# How to display labels with 0/null values gauge promethues

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using a `gauge` in `grafana` to represent my `promethues` query. Below is my query but when there are no values the bar is removed from graphana. How can I fix this and display the label even when there are `0` values for that bar.

```
sum(duration_metric_count{env=~"TEST|DEV|PROD", server=~"$server}) by (env)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options.

- If you're using the "Graph" panel, then set the "Panel > Display > Stacking and null value > Null value" option to "null as zero"

[image]

- If you're using the "Bar gauge" panel, then set the "Field > Standard options > No Value" option to "0"

[image]

Comment: Is this option available for a bar gauge

Comment: I added more info.